# Roles of Public Certificate (cer) and TLS in FTP Client

Tags: c#, ftp, certificate, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

What are the roles of public certificate and TLS in FTP Client when connecting to FTP server?

1 Is it safe to disable server certificate validation from client and use TLS only? like below.

Preferably, can method 1 below be used because it doesn't require certificate being used on client, compared to #2 at the bottom?

```
 FtpClient client = new FtpClient(hostname, username, password); // or set Host & Credentials
    client.EncryptionMode = FtpEncryptionMode.Explicit;
    client.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls;
    client.ValidateCertificate += new FtpSslValidation(OnValidateCertificate);
    client.Connect();    
    void OnValidateCertificate(FtpClient control, FtpSslValidationEventArgs e) {
        //Ignore test if certificate is valid here by setting true
        e.Accept = true;
    }
```

Please see "How do I validate the server's certificate when using FTPS?"
https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP#faq_ftps

How do I validate the server's certificate when using FTPS?

Method 1: Connect if the SSL certificate has no errors.

```
client.ValidateCertificate += new FtpSslValidation(delegate (FtpClient c, FtpSslValidationEventArgs e) {
    if (e.PolicyErrors != System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None){
        e.Accept = false;
    }else{
        e.Accept = true;
    }
});
```

Method 2: Connect if the certificate matches a whitelisted certificate.

First you must discover the string of the valid certificate. Use this code to save the valid certificate string to a file:

```
client.ValidateCertificate += new FtpSslValidation(delegate (FtpClient c, FtpSslValidationEventArgs e) {
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\cert.txt", e.Certificate.GetRawCertDataString());
});
```

Then finally use this code to check if the received certificate matches the one you trust:

```
string ValidCert = "<insert contents of cert.txt>";
client.ValidateCertificate += new FtpSslValidation(delegate (FtpClient c, FtpSslValidationEventArgs e) {
    if (e.PolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None || e.Certificate.GetRawCertDataString() == ValidCert) {
        e.Accept = true;
    }else{
        throw new Exception("Invalid certificate : " + e.PolicyErrors);
    }
});
```

2 By comparison, below uses "client certificates to login with FTPS"
  The **problem** of using this method is it requires client certificates or server's public certificate.

```
  client.EncryptionMode = FtpEncryptionMode.Explicit;
    client.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12;
    client.SocketKeepAlive = false;
    client.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("C:\mycert.cer"));
    client.ValidateCertificate += (control, e) => {
        e.Accept = e.PolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
    };
    client.Connect();
```

Please see How do I use client certificates to login with FTPS?
https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP#faq_certs

**Update**

I was given a server's public certificate, in this case, are both two methods above (method 2 and #2 using the same certificate?

Comment: If you really go over the background https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security You will understand various details the answer below explained. Ask yourself if you want to trust a server and how, or how to trust a client and how, then that answer already illustrated enough for you to digest.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the roles of public certificate

TLS/SSL uses certificates. Certificates should be signed by a trusted authority. So in general, you should not need to verify it, as it should get verified against the trusted authorities (but I do not know if  FluentFTP actually supports that). If the FTP client does not support verifying against trusted authorities or if the FTP server certificate is self-signed, you need to verify the certificate yourself. If you do not, you are not safe, as you lose a protection against [Man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

If you are familiar with SSH, it is similar as if you blindly accept an SSH hostkey (fingerprint) in SSH.

> What are the roles of ... TLS

TLS is encryption layer. The same as in HTTPS (which also uses TLS).

> Is it safe to disable server certificate validation from client and use TLS only?

A certificate is an integral part of TLS (those are not two separate things). If you do not verify the certificate, the TLS won't protect you completely.

> By comparison, below uses server public certificate:

No it does not. That code uses *client* certificate to *authenticate* the user. That has nothing to do with *verifying* *server* (public - sic) certificate. You still have to verify the certificate.

Though if `e.Accept = e.PolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None` works, your *server* certificate is valid and signed by a trusted authority and you have nothing to worry about.

Again, this is similar to SSH *server* and *user* key pair. See my article on [Understanding SSH Key Pairs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys), just think *"certificate"*, where the article talks about *"key"*.

Comment: Do you mean using TLS without validating server certificate is not safe? Please see my update on OP.

Comment: 1) Yes. That's what my answer says in the first paragraph.  2) About your "difference" question. I do not know what you ask for. Those are two different methods to verify a certificate. That's the difference. 3) *"Client certificates"* are for a completely new question. That has nothing to do with verifying server public certificates.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Please see my update again on OP.

Comment: Verifying server certificate is always necessary. Using a client certificate to authenticate is optional and has nothing to do with server's public certificate. Those *"two methods"* that you refer to in your question are **not alternatives**. They **serve a completely different purpose**. Again, read the article I've suggested in my answer. Also note that the sample implementation of `OnValidateCertificate` with `e.Accept = true;` is not secure at all. You have to provide your custom implementation with a use of *"given a server's public certificate"*.

Comment: This looks more and more like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578). Ask about what your want to implement. Rather than asking about various code snippets that you (mostly incorrectly) believe are related to what you are implementing. This is not a chat, this is Q&A site.